# Websocket - problem - No route found for path 'ws'

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, channel

I'm not quite good at web sockets - Django channels, trying understand.

Have this problem on daphne

```
   File "/Users/ozov/ERA/PYTHON/Enviroments_created/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 134, in __call__
   raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws'.
127.0.0.1:60559 - - [30/May/2023:08:21:09] "WSDISCONNECT /ws" - -
^C2023-05-30 08:22:13,364 INFO     Killed 0 pending application instances
```

this problem on running.  daphne -p 8001 chat.routing:application

the project is  **https://github.com/narrowfail/django-channels-chat**

I guess the problem is in routing.py

```
from core import consumers
from django.conf.urls import url

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

In app.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateUserList();
    disableInput();


    var socket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' + '127.0.0.1:8001' +
        '/ws?session_key=${sessionKey}')

    chatInput.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
            chatButton.click();
    });
```

I put 127.0.0.1:8001 because Daphne is running on 8001

thanks for help!!

I really don't understand why he don't like.

in chrome I have such logs:

```
app.js:93 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8001/ws?session_key=${sessionKey}' failed
```

consumers.py

## chat/consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        user_id = self.scope["session"]["_auth_user_id"]
        self.group_name = "{}".format(user_id)
        # Join room group

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data=None,bytes_data = None):

        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.chat_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'recieve_group_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def recieve_group_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(
             text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```